# how to print silent mode in chrome with os linux

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, printing, kiosk-mode, silent

**i tried enabled PDF compositor service for printing has not succeeded** 
 *Us PDF compositor service for printing
When enabled, use PDF compositor service to composite and generate PDF files for printing. When site isolation is enabled, disabling this will not stop using PDF compositor service since the service is required for printing out-of-process iframes correctly. – Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android*
[image]

Comment: PDF compositor is not related to this. The only method of silent PDF printing for a chrome app/extension is to use `chrome.debugger` API and send [Page.printToPDF](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-printToPDF) command. I didn't do it so look for examples or extensions like that yourself.

Comment: Thank you, i will try it